# How to add size property to catplot kind point in seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, catplot

I have generated a seaborn `catplot` with `kind=point` as follows:

```
ax = sns.catplot(
    x     =  "bins",
    y     =  "sigma",
    hue   =  "conditions",
    data  =  DB,
    col_wrap = 2,
    errorbar = "sd",
    col_order = ["V1d", "V1v", "V2d", "V2v", "V3a", "V3v", "V5", "V4", "V3d"],
    kind  =  "point",
    palette = HUE_COLORS,
    col   =  "rois",
    dodge = False,
    join = False,
    scale = 1.5,
)
```

`data` is taken from "DB" database. "bins" is the `x` categorical variable (type `string`) while "sigma" the `y` independent variable (type `float`).
The plot is divided into several subplot defined with the "rois" variable for `col`.

[image]
*Image from one roi*

I would like each point to have different size depending on the "sigma" value (i.e., the bigger the sigma the bigger the point).

I managed to do so using the `scatterplot` plot, that in turn, does not have the error bars, which I need.

Is there a way to add the size property to catplot with kind as point?
Thank you all!

---

- The answers provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58548261/how-to-change-marker-size-in-seaborn-catplot) do not solve my issue. They work only with plain `catplot`, but when I add `kind=point` it doesn't work.
- The answer provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38496527/can-i-change-one-marker-size-on-a-point-plot#:%7E:text=Not%20through%20the%20seaborn%20API%2C%20but%20it%27s%20possible%20by%20manipulating%20the%20matplotlib%20objects%20after%20plotting%20%E2%80%94%20something%20like%3A) does not help. The object does not contain "collections" property.

Comment: Otherwise use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html)

Comment: Thank you, yep I thought to opt for that. I just need to make avg from sigmas from each bin.